# Regenerating /usr/share/locale/ on Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, locale, localization

Is there a way to regenerate deleted locale on /usr/share/locale without downloading the application again?

Answer (score 1):

Only if you made a [backup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backup) of it.